# How to add comma to a select from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql code in my C program.

```
SELECT `Log_count`,`Failed_count`,`value`,`Date` FROM `login` WHERE `user_id` = %d;
```

My question is the following, it is possible to use select format in the following columns of mysql **Log_count, Failed_count, value**

Comment: That doesn't seem clear enough for me... Do you mean replacing the column names in that select query with more selects? Like `SELECT (SELECT ...), (SELECT ...) FROM ...`?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JMichelB I want to change the SELECT by SELECT FORMAT. So I wanted to know how to apply SELECT FORMAT on only the 3 columns.   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
 SELECT FORMAT(`Log_count`    ,0) AS `Log_count`
      , FORMAT(`Failed_count` ,0) AS `Failed_count`
      , FORMAT(`value`        ,4) AS `value`
      , `Date`                    AS `Date`
   FROM ...
```